# GIT: pulling a branch results in a conflict. Why?

Tags: git, version-control

I have some local version of a some branch. It was pulled some time ago. Now I want to update that branch with a fresh updates. I call

```
git fetch;
git pull;
```

And I get a number of conflicts in my working directory!

Why this happens?
Before pull my working directory was clean. No commits from my side. No divergence possible. And despite this I see conflicts.

Why this happens?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like the reason is that the branch was deleted and then re-created.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have changes that need to be committed before you `pull`. Make sure you commit your changes *before* you `pull`

Also, you don't need to `pull` *and* `fetch`: `pull` calls `fetch`. Please see documentation on [Git pull Operation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?rq=1). I also recommend you search for "Git best practices". You'll find a whole host of articles on the interwebs, e.g. [an effective Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model).

Comment: Thanks, Austin, looks like the reason is that the branch was deleted and then re-created.